# Countdown quantity by a specific date

Tags: javascript, countdown

Currently using the below code but the problem is that the quantity refreshes every page load. Basically need to start at 100 and countdown to 0 by a specific date.

```
    <h1>Product QTY</h1>
<div id="prod-qty">
  <div>
    <span class="qty" id="qty"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Left In Stock</div>
  </div>  
</div>

<script>
    var qty = 57
    var qtyId = document.getElementById("qty");

    setQty(qty);

    function setQty(qty)
    {
        qtyId.innerHTML = qty;

        if (qty==0) return;

        var parts = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        if (parts > qty) parts = qty;

        var msec =  Math.floor(((Math.random() * 15) + 15)*1000);

        qty -= parts;

        setTimeout(function() {
            setQty(qty);
        }, msec)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have a look at *localStorage*

Comment: Not sure if the same mistake is in your actual code but watch the quotes you use. These, `id=“prod-qty”` aren't the ones you want. `'` or `"`

Comment: Can you please clarify "*100 and countdown to 0 by a specific date*"? Like how often do you want 100 to decrease? Every day? Starting from a particular day? Do you want to do this on the server, or the client?

Comment: @ObsidianAge basically just want it to decrease by 10 every day. The rule is there to change the quantity by 3 or 1 every 15-30 seconds. This will obviously change to hours.

Comment: @j08691 edited. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to do? It seems like it takes a random number of "parts" from "qty" every once in a while, not 10 per day as your comment notes. As @Jonasw mentioned, [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) will store the quantity value over page refreshes.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the code currently just countdowns from the var qty that's set which is 57. It decreases the amount by 3 or 1 every 15-30 seconds. Once the page refreshes so does the code and it goes back to 57

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of lame, but shows that you can figure out the elapsed time and deduct a part for every minute that has passed.

```js
/* starting quantity */
var qty = 100;
var qtyId = document.getElementById("qty");

/* the start time: June 21, 2017 2:15 PM */
var startDate = new Date(2017, 5, 21, 14, 15);

/* The time now, minus the start time. Divide by 1000 to get seconds instead of milliseconds */
var elapsed = (Date.now() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000;

/* adjust the start quantity by some amount. In this case, just take the number of seconds and divide by 60 to get the number of minutes. So remove a part for every minute that has passed. */
qty -= parseInt(elapsed / 60);

/* now do everything you did before */
setQty(qty);

function setQty(qty) {
  qtyId.innerHTML = qty;

  if (qty == 0) return;

  var parts = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  if (parts > qty) parts = qty;

  var msec = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 15) + 15) * 1000);

  qty -= parts;

  setTimeout(function() {
    setQty(qty);
  }, msec)
}
```

```html
<h1>Product QTY</h1>
<span id="qty"></span>
<span>Left In Stock</span>
```

Comment: Seems like this could work. What are 5, 21, 14, 15 supposed to mean? Currently shows a negative number

Comment: Same thing, when refreshed. The quantity goes back

Comment: Seems like it worked now. It's changing 1 every minute right now. How can I change it to lets say every hour or so

Comment: Also looks like this part isn't necessary `if (qty == 0) return;

  var parts = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  if (parts > qty) parts = qty;

  var msec = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 15) + 15) * 1000);
`

Comment: `qty -= parseInt(elapsed / 60);` elapsed is seconds. So divide by 60 to get minutes. Divide by 60 again to get hours. `qty -= parseInt(elapsed / 60 / 60);`

Comment: So this `qty -= parseInt(elapsed / 60 / 60);` would decrease 1 every hour?

Comment: Yep. It would decrease `qty` for each hour that passed since the start time. It's a pretty contrived example because it depends on the clock on the client-side but if you're just whipping up an example or a demo, it will work in a pinch.

Comment: This works perfectly so far. What would be the example for lets say 2 or 4 hours

Answer (score 0):

It might actually be easier to use Jonas suggestion and use LocalStorage. Here's an example:
https://lab-jesjbhtqfh.now.sh

And documentation about LocalStorage:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage